# How to randomize Point Light power or color with Geonodes

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, geometry-nodes

How can I randomize power or color with Geonodes Point Light?
I tried to type in "power" or "energy" or "color" No changes were taken.

It works with scale, but not a power or color.

[image: screenshot of randomly distributed lights]

[image: screenshot of geometry nodes]

Comment: I don't think this is possible using geometry nodes, since point light is not a geometry. Try using animation nodes addon for this kind of stuff.