# Controlling light's power by geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, lighting

Someone know if it's possible to control the 'Power' of a light with Geometry Nodes with Blender 3.6.

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265282/passing-geonodes-attribute-to-shader-frame-offset) You can drive the light power just like you would drive anything else. See the right "Linked" column there for more examples of this technique.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285192/is-it-possible-to-get-camera-information-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285772/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248482/

Comment: Thanks for the replies :D